# Handling exception in main function interface

Tags: python, function, exception

I have a main function that takes a list argument and proceeds with every element in the list. It is not necessary for me to stop the program whenever one element raises an exception. The problem is that the input list is passed through different functions and it is a pain to handle exceptions for all those functions.

Is there any way to continue to proceed with the next element when the current element in the list raises an exception?

Let's say func3 raise an exception at list_[0], then main will continue with list_[1] from func1, and then func2,... –

Some pseudo-code:

```
def main(list_) -> None:   
    func1(list_)
    func2(list_)
    func3(list_)
```

Expected behavior:

```
def main(list_) -> None:   
    try:
        func1(list_)
        func2(list_)
        func3(list_)
    except:
        continue with the next element
        print(Element i raise Exception..., Skipping i...)
```

Comment: Your edit made the question less clear rather than more clear.  Are you intending to call `func1(list_[0])`, `func2(list_[1])`, etc?  Or to call each function on the entire list?  Or to call each function on each element of the list individually?  Maybe you could provide some sample `func1...3` definitions and a value for `list_` and explain what you expect to have happen.

Comment: @Samwise I should call func(list_) but func proceeds the list_ element by element. I want whenever if any element throws an exception inside func then my program will skip that element and get back to the main function and continue with the next element.

Comment: That would need to happen inside the definition of `func`, not in its caller.  The caller can't see what specifically `func` is doing with the list, much less tell it "no, go back and pick up where you left off".  This highlights the need for you to post an example definition of `func` rather than just `main`.  The `try`/`except` needs to happen inside the loop that `func` is doing.

Comment: It would be possible to have `main` inject an exception handler into `func`, which might accomplish what you're looking for -- but we need actual runnable code!

Answer (score 1):

Each function needs to be in its own `try` block.

```
def main(list_) -> None:
    for f in (func1, func2, func3):
        try:
            f(list_)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: I am sorry that my question wasn't very clear, I have updated it

Answer (score 0):

With a “reversed” list of the functions, this `while-loop` might be suitable for the body of the main function:

```py
funcs = [funcN, funcN-1, …, func2, func1]
while any(funcs):
    try: funcs.pop()(list_)
    except: continue
```

Comment: this skip the function and continue to proceed to the next function, what I want is to skip the element from the input list_. Let's say we are proceeding with list_[0], if list_[0] raises Exceptions, main will continue with list_[1].

Answer (score 0):

If all your functions has the same input `list_`, the other answers should be enough and are preferable due to simplicity. But in case the arguments vary, you might want to wrap the call to those functions inside a decorator in where you would catch the errors:

#### Style 1

```
def catch_exc(func, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception as error:
        print(func, "Element i raise Exception..., Skipping i...", error)
    else:
        print(func, "Success")

def func1(list_): raise Exception("Anything")
def func2(list_): raise Exception("Something")
def func3(list_): return "Success"
def func4(list_): raise Exception("Whatever")

def main(list_) -> None:
    catch_exc(func1, list_)
    catch_exc(func2, list_)
    catch_exc(func3, list_)
    catch_exc(func4, list_)

main([1,2,3,4])
```

#### Style 2

```
def catch_exc(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):  # Ideally decorate this with <functools.wraps(func)>
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as error:
            print(func, "Element i raise Exception..., Skipping i...", error)
        else:
            print(func, "Success")
    return wrapper

@catch_exc
def func1(list_): raise Exception("Anything")
@catch_exc
def func2(list_): raise Exception("Something")
@catch_exc
def func3(list_): return "Success"
@catch_exc
def func4(list_): raise Exception("Whatever")

def main(list_) -> None:
    func1(list_)
    func2(list_)
    func3(list_)
    func4(list_)

main([1,2,3,4])
```

**Output**

```
<function func1 at 0x149f3d911c10> Element i raise Exception..., Skipping i... Anything
<function func2 at 0x149f3d911ee0> Element i raise Exception..., Skipping i... Something
<function func3 at 0x149f3d911f70> Success
<function func4 at 0x149f3d91b040> Element i raise Exception..., Skipping i... Whatever
```

Comment: I am sorry that my question wasn't very clear, I want to keep proceed with the next element in the list. Let's say func3 raise an exception at list_[0], then main will continue with list_[1] from func1, and then func2,...